# Authentication failed

Tags: ssh

```
You have no controlling tty and no DISPLAY.  Cannot read passphrase.
warning: Authentication failed.
Disconnected (local); authentication cancelled by user (Authentication cancelled by user.).
Disconnect reason 13, exit code = 77
scp: warning: ssh2 client failed to authenticate. (or you have too old ssh2 installed, check with ssh2 -V)
```

I get this error when I run my script. ssh is working in both ways between the servers

Comment: What script? What command are you running? What are you ultimately trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using some kind of authentication method which requires a user input (in your case, apparently, a passphrase to decrypt a private key, or maybe a password) but your program cannot receive any user input because it's not launched in a graphical session (preventing `ssh` to spawn a window form asking for the passphrase) nor in a terminal (so `ssh` cannot ask you interactively for the passphrase).

`ssh` works when you test opening a session because in this case you are launching `ssh` in a terminal so there is no problem to get the passphrase.

What you need if your script run without a controlling tty (for example, as a cron job) is a non-interactive authentication. For example, a private key without passphrase. Of course, this is somewhat insecure and you probably want to restrict the set of commands executable by your script through ssh to prevent attackers who would get to know the private key to get a fully-featured shell on the server.